# Multiple nested if statment in MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying the query below and MySQL gave me this error: Invalid use of group function

```
 SELECT C.`some_name`,
        SUM(IF(A.`med_type` = 1, SUM(A.`med_qty`), 0)) AS total,
        SUM(IF(A.`is_rejected` = 4, 1 , 0)) AS approved, 
        SUM(IF(A.`is_rejected` = 2, 1 , 0)) AS qeue, 
        SUM(IF(A.`is_rejected` = 3, 1 , 0)) AS rejected, 
        SUM(IF(A.`is_rejected` = 1, 1 , 0)) AS fresh
   FROM `ne_media` A
  INNER JOIN `ne_member` B ON A.`mem_id`  = B.`mem_id`
  INNER JOIN `ne_some`   C ON B.`some_id` = C.`some_id`
  GROUP BY C.`some_id`;
```

I want to sum `med_qty` just if `med_type = 1`.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
    SUM(CASE WHEN (A.`med_type` = 1) THEN A.`med_qty` ELSE 0 END)) AS total,
```

or:

```
    SUM(IF(A.`med_type` = 1, A.`med_qty`, 0)) AS total,
```

You can't do aggregates on aggregates like you tried to in the original.

Comment: tanks it works but actually i need sum of the content of the med_qty not count of them this is return count of them . !

Comment: It would count them if you summed 1 or 0 as in your other expressions, but if you sum the `med_qty` values when `med_type` is 1, as shown, you should get what you requested.